# Adding string to integer

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, integer, percentage

I need to have the percentage sign after the calculation, how can i change this code so the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

is not displayed. To remove the decimal point the calculation is 'int'.

```
global score
score = 2

def test(score):
    percentage = int(((score)/5)*100) + ("%")
    print (percentage)

test(score)
```

Comment: Cast your number to a string.

Comment: you *still* need to convert the number *back* to str.

Answer (score 5):

Use string formatting:

```
print('{:.0%}'.format(score/5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `str(int(((score)/5)*100)) + ("%")`

Answer (score 1):

In python (and a lot of other languages), the `+` operator serves a dual purpose. It can be used to get the sum of two numbers (number + number), or concatenate strings (string + string). In this case, python can't decide what the `+` should do, as one of your operands is a number, and the other is a string.

To fix this, you'll have to alter one operand to match the type of the other. In this case, your only option is to make the number into a string (easily done using the built-in [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) function:

```
str(int(((score)/5)*100)) + "%"
```

Or, you can ditch `+` entirely and go with format syntax.

**Old syntax:**

```
"%d%%" % int(((score)/5)*100)
```

**New syntax:**

```
'{}%'.format(int(((score)/5)*100))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you cannot apply the `+` operator between an int and a string. You could, however, convert the int to a string yourself:

```
percentage = str(int(((score)/5)*100)) + ("%")
# Here ------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
global score
score = 2

def test(score):
    percentage = str(int(((score)/5)*100)) + "%"
    print (percentage)

test(score)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python >= 3.6:

```
percentage = f"{(score / 5) * 100}%"
print(percentage)
```